# Attribute to enforce padding after a variable?

Tags: c++, padding, memory-alignment

Is there an attribute to enforce padding after a variable?

I have a volatile (non-cached) variable declared as such:

```
volatile int foo __attribute__((aligned(CACHE_LINE_SIZE));
```

I would like to prevent other variables from being allocated to the same cache line, to avoid coherency issues.
I can add a padding variable after foo, or set the `__attribute__((aligned(CACHE_LINE_SIZE))` to the following variable in the same compilation unit. However I was wondering whether there is a cleaner way to do this, such as adding an attribute to variable `foo` itself to enforce padding.

Comment: something along `struct { int foo; char padding[CACHE_LINE_SIZE - sizeof(int)]; }`?

Comment: Does [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) do what you want ?

Comment: @KamilCuk With your definition, there is no guarantee that an object will be mapped to a single cache line only.

Comment: The `union { int foo; char size[CACHE_LINE_SIZE]; }` looks even better.

Comment: @RichardCritten Even if it did, `std::aligned_storage` has been deprecated in C++23.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some options are introduced in this blog article: [Aligning data with cache lines](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/iot-&-hardware/9781838821043/3/ch03lvl1sec27/aligning-data-with-cache-lines).

I would suggest to use the C++11 [alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas):

The simplest version

```cpp
using my_padded_type = struct alignas(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) { int value;} ;
```

Padding bits are added automatically.
You can verify it by checking `sizeof(my_padded_type)`. See details below.

Other options:

```cpp
alignas(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) int foo1, foo2;
alignas(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) union { int value; char size[CACHE_LINE_SIZE]; } foo;

std::cout  << "&foo1: " << &foo1 << '\t'
           << "&foo2: " << &foo2 << '\n';
// &foo1: 0x7ffd833ebe00 &foo2: 0x7ffd833ebe40
```

or

```
struct alignas(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) my_padded_type {
    int foo;  //  size: 4 
    char p;   //  do not need to specify length here. this line can be omitted entirely
    // auto padding so that sizeof(my_padded_type) == CACHE_LINE_SIZE
}; 
my_padding_type foo;
std::cout<< sizeof(my_padding_type) <<"\n"; // equals CACHE_LINE_SIZE
```

The padding is done automatically by the compiler, see the example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment).

Answer (score 4):

This is what [`std::hardware_destructive_interference_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size) was added for:

```cpp
struct X
{
    alignas(std::hardware_destructive_interference_size) int Foo;
    alignas(std::hardware_destructive_interference_size) int Bar; // Foo and Bar are on different cache lines
};
```

```cpp
alignas(std::hardware_destructive_interference_size)
struct Foo // Foo is guaranteed to be on its own cache line
{
};
```

Comment: Can you find a reference / standard documentation about the behavior of `alignas(64) struct Foo {}`? I have tested in GCC/Clang. Both compiler do guarantee `Foo` to be on its own cache line. However I cannot find any guarantee in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 3):

`alignas(CACHE_LINE_SIZE)` on every variable should to the trick:

```
struct X {
    alignas(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) int foo;
    alignas(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) int bar;
};
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Wcc86YaW)

I assume you are asking about aligning struct members.

If you don't care about the alignment of subsequent members, but want to make sure that no other data is placed on `foo`'s cache line, manually fill it with padding bytes:

```
struct X {
    alignas(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) int foo;
    char paddingbytes[CACHE_LINE_SIZE - sizeof(int)];
    // Other data members
};
```